# Using get_cycles() in kernel module fails: Unknown symbol in module

Tags: time, linux-kernel, arm

I wish to do some precise timing to measure the power line frequency. According to Linux Device Drivers, I can call get_cycles() defined in timex.h to do so. The following code compiles, but insmod complains `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./fmod.ko: Unknown symbol in module`
This is an ARM design, i.MX 6UltraLite Applications Processor, Arm® Cortex®-A7 core

```
root@ts-imx6ul:/home/holden# uname -a                                           
Linux ts-imx6ul 4.1.15-g9c4c55a #2 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 3 15:57:11 PDT 2023 armvx
```

Any suggestions how to do some detailed timing?

```
#include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>         /* Needed for the macros */

#include <linux/timex.h>

static int __init hello_start(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading hello module...\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world\n");

    cycles_t time = get_cycles();

    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_end(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye Mr.\n");
}

module_init(hello_start);
module_exit(hello_end);
```

Comment: `dmesg` should give more detailed information about the problem. Add this information into the question post.

Comment: dmesg informs us [59584.957046] fmod: Unknown symbol read_current_timer (err 0)

Answer (score 1):

Function `read_current_timer` is [exported](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.3/source/arch/arm/lib/delay.c#L38) with `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL` macro. So it can be used only by modules with **GPL-compatible license**. E.g. you could add to your module.

```c
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: For other GPL-compatible license strings that can be used, see the `license_is_gpl_compatible(license)` inline function in "include/linux/license.h".